# Require JS in different levels of dependency

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm working with Javascript and I'm working with a project too long to development application with Phonegap and googlemaps but now I focused in the code with Javascript, but now I've the next structure of directories and scripts inside *js* directory:

```
├── controlador
│   └── DeviceController.js
├── launcher.js
├── libs
│   ├── backbone.googlemaps.js
│   ├── backbone.js
│   ├── class.js
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── jquery.js
│   ├── jquery.mobile.min.js
│   ├── mustache.js
│   ├── require.js
│   └── underscore.js
├── modelo
│   └── Ubicacion.js
└── vista
   ├── GoogleMap.js
   ├── Informacion.js
   ├── MarcadorBahia.js
   ├── MarcadorDispositivo.js
   ├── MarcadorParqueadero.js
   └── MarkerView.js
```

So, I use [class library](http://www.uselesspickles.com/class_library/) to work with object in javascript more easy, and I tried to work with Backbone and  I did this [example](https://gist.github.com/cristianchaparroa/d614729df8abeec36c49),  it works!.

**My problem** is when I try to work with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), I don't get to load the scripts  the right way.

This is the mistakes that show me the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: com is not defined launcher.js:18
(anonymous function) launcher.js:18
i.execCb require.js:29
Z.check require.js:18
(anonymous function) require.js:22
(anonymous function) require.js:8
(anonymous function) require.js:23
y require.js:7
Z.emit require.js:23
Z.check require.js:19
Z.enable require.js:23
Z.init require.js:16
E require.js:14
i.completeLoad require.js:27
i.onScriptLoad require.js:29

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of undefined Ubicacion.js:11
(anonymous function) Ubicacion.js:11
i.execCb require.js:29
Z.check require.js:18
Z.enable require.js:23
Z.init require.js:16
(anonymous function)
```

This is the code of  the entry point of my application, the *launcher.js*:

```js
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery      : 'libs/jquery',
        googlemapapi: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC35BOQq2RvkKjzh0NhohKbQtUa3KWBM1o&sensor=false',  
        underscore  : 'libs/underscore',
        backbone    : 'libs/backbone',
        mustache    : 'libs/mustache',
        class       : 'libs/class',
        ubicacion   : 'modelo/Ubicacion',  // this class I required by DeviceController
        deviceController: 'controlador/DeviceController'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'mustache',  'class','ubicacion','deviceController' ], 
function($, _,Backbone,Mustache ) 
{ 
   var deviceController = new com.gcvv.bsp.controller.DeviceController();
});
```

The class DeviceController is:

```js
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','class','ubicacion' ], 
function($, _, Backbone ){

$namespace( "com.gcvv.bsp.controller" );

$class( "com.gcvv.bsp.controller.DeviceController",{
     $constructor: function(){
         this.ubicacion = com.gcvv.bsp.modelo.Ubicacion(0,0);
     },
     getPosicionActual: function()
     {
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.localizacion, this.error);
        }else{
            console.error("El dispositivo no soporta geolocalizacion");
        }
     },
     localizacion : function(posicion){
         this.ubication.set( 'longitud',posicion.coords.latitude );
         this.ubication.set( 'latitud', posicion.coords.longitude);
     },
     error : function(){
         console.error("Error al obtener la gelocalización del dispositivo");
     }
});

});
```

this is the code of *Ubicacion.js*:

```js
require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','class'], 
function($, _, Backbone) {
$namespace( "com.gcvv.bsp.modelo" );
$class("com.gcvv.bsp.modelo.Ubicacion",{
    $extends: Backbone.Model,   
    defaults: {
        longitud: 0,
        latitude: 0
    }
}); 
});
```

I try to make a unit test to  understand that the trouble is the level of the  context to define the dependencies(well I suppose it), I try the next things:

1. I use the class inside of DeviceController(Ubicacion) to test that this works
   fine
2. In the  Ubicacion class I remove the statment of require.

```js
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery      : 'libs/jquery',
        googlemapapi: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC35BOQq2RvkKjzh0NhohKbQtUa3KWBM1o&sensor=false',  
        underscore  : 'libs/underscore',
        backbone    : 'libs/backbone',
        mustache    : 'libs/mustache',
        class       : 'libs/class',
        ubicacion   : 'modelo/Ubicacion',
        deviceController: 'controlador/DeviceController'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'mustache', 'class','ubicacion','deviceController' ], 
function($, _,Backbone,Mustache, $class, Ubicacion  ) 
{ 
  var ubicacion = new com.gcvv.bsp.modelo.Ubicacion(); 
  console.log( ubicacion.get('longitud') ); //I get 0, default value 
 });
```

So, the  Ubicacion class with the changes:

```js
$namespace( "com.gcvv.bsp.modelo" );
$class("com.gcvv.bsp.modelo.Ubicacion",{
    $extends: Backbone.Model,   
    defaults: {
        longitud: 0,
        latitude: 0
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

How to define the right structure of the require dependecies in each file that I need to use?

How do I do if I use the same dependencies in different scripts to not reloaded?

How do I do if I use the same dependencies in different scripts so they do not present conflicts?

How to define the right structre of the entry point of my application?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error then i refer this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/camunda-bpm-users/mnd1RXAiR50/veSaemAPVmAJ

Just clear your cache

Hope it's workout for you also.